# Apply settings to multiple output columns in SSIS flat file source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, export, ssis-2014

Is there an easier way to apply property settings to multiple output columns in a SSIS flat file source, rather than manually applying to each output column? (SQL Server 2014.)  I am attempting to export data from a large text file source to an Azure database and the process is very slow.  I have read some tuning guides that suggest that the "FastParse" and "Length" properties should be set.  The problem is, my data source is columnar (which is transposed to rows further down the track) and it is tedious to set properties individually for a large amount of columns.

In general it would also be beneficial to know if it is possible to bulk-apply other such settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the advanced tab of the connection manager of the flat file data source. You can mark multiple columns by holding CTRL and then set the properties they have in common.

Comment: You are talking about the connection manager properties.  I was referring to the properties on output columns for the 'Flat File Source' task which is found under the advanced editor for the task "Input and Output Properties".  For those properties, I can only select a single item at a time.